# Authorize users based on Google "hosted domain"

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to authorize my users based on their Google "hosted domain". This is equivalent to their G Suite organization and is a claim on the Google OpenID claim as "hd".

I reason that a custom claim makes a good place to put this information so that in Firestore I can do `request.auth.token.hd == 'xyz.org'`.

I want to also verify that when users login to my app, that they are still part of the organization.

How do I create this solution in Firebase?

Should I use `signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential`? Is `providerData` static or does it update every time `signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential` is called?

Comment: Do your users use a unique custom domain: user@xyz.org?

Comment: Yes, for the most part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44274930/381285

I think I need the `result.additionalUserInfo.profile` to get my claim information. It won't be on `result.user.providerData` because that's an array of `UserInfo` data.

Now I think the tricky part is to get that updated in a secure way on the database / custom claim.

Probably should bind to `onIdTokenChanged` that fires a cloud function that verifies `googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token` contains my claim. Then update my firebase id token claim with the information. And once my custom claim is updated I will again need to refresh my client's ID token because custom claims don't automatically propagate.